# В чем ошибка отправлений данных через ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Всем доброго времени суток,отправляю ajax'ом id в таблицу на удаление,беру через инпут.Выскакивает функция success,пишет,что все выполнено
НО
 как закрываю алер,сразу перезагружается страница.
index.php

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btn-delete").bind("click",function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'file.php',
                    data : ({id:$("#input-name").val()}),
                    success : function(data){
                        alert("Выполнено");
                    }   
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<form>
    <p>Удаление<br>
        <label>Введите айди пользователя</label>
        <input type="text" name="input-name" id="input-name">
        <button id="btn-delete">Удалить</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

file.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  $id=$_POST["id"];
}
function delete($pdo,$id){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id =".$id;
  $del = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $del->execute();
}
```

Всем заранее благодарю за ответы:)

Comment: @Other Можете просмотреть 2 файла,по идеи там не должно быть перезагрузке,так как в file.php там только идет вывод таблицы из бд.
https://goo.gl/GdER8x index.php
https://goo.gl/Du4JVW file.php
Буду очень благодарен за потраченное время)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, `<button>`, расположенный в форме выполняет роль инпута с типом `submit`. Поэтому, в данном случае, нужно делать тоже самое, что при клике на ссылку, при клике на которую хочется отменить дефолтное поведение:

```
$("#btn-delete").bind("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // всё остальное
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

Ваша кнопка без атрибута `type` находится в форме.
Для таких кнопок, `type` по умолчанию равен `submit`, она отправляет форму по нажатию.
Чтобы предотвратить это поведение, вы можете либо вызвать `event.preventDefault()` в обработчике клика, либо изменить `type` на `button`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)